# When and why is a reimport of all maven projects required?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Occasionally, after an SVN update where POM's have changed, IntelliJ does not seem to notice this and you start having strange behaviors (non-existing classes, methods, ...). I know now that reimporting all maven projects fixes the issue but I don't understand why this is necessary.

I have checked 'Import Maven projects automatically'.

I don't think it's a bug since this was already the case in version 12 and still is in 13.

Comment: `Import Maven projects automatically` should handle such situations. If it doesn't work, please [file a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the steps to reproduce and a test case.

Comment: Just had the issue again; all our pom's were updated from snapshot-X to snapshot-Y. A make showed errors that did not seem to be valid. An import all and make fixed the problem. This is not just me by the way, we all have migrated from eclipse to IntelliJ and all have this issue now and then.

Comment: To be clear, this is not a reason to go back to eclipse :-).

Comment: Do you have `Use Maven3` option in the `Settings` | `Maven` | `Importing` enabled?

Comment: If you mean 'Use Maven3 to import project' then yes. Actually, apart from the first checkbox (Keep project files in) all are checked on this settings page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is usually a dependency problem relating to transitive dependencies. If you're relying on transitive dependencies between your modules then IntelliJ will likely have problems recognizing that an automatic re-import is needed. Best practice is to list all your direct dependencies in each module. Then, when a module is changed and rebuilt or re-imported the modules that depend on it will be rebuilt. So, my advice is check your dependencies and ensure that there are no transitives in your tree - 'mvn dependency:tree' may help.

Comment: Tx. We have about 140 (maven) projects so it would be some work to check all of them but if I get it chance I'll try to reproduce this on some test workspace.

Comment: Problem resolved by listing all dependencies to our other artifacts in the dependency management of the parent pom if our project. It's very similar to what you suggested so thanks for the tip.